# sending VIRB X url livePreview doesn't affect resolution

Tags: garmin

I'm just using a basic linux environment. When I issue the following commands, per https://developer.garmin.com/downloads/virb/Camera_Network_Services_API.pdf, I get the camera URL. Pasting this into VLC, I do indeed get the live preview from the camera. However, the resolution is always 432x258 with a display resolution of 432x240.

Modifying the maxResolutionVertical field does not change anything. Am I missing something? I really want to get a full 1920x1080 video stream from my camera.

```
curl --data "{\"command\":\"livePreview\",\"streamType\":\"rtp\",\"maxResolutionVertical\":\"1080\",\"liveStreamActive\":\"1\"}" http://192.168.86.117/virb
```

I've tried changing it to minResolutionVertical with 1080 as well, with no difference. I even set the maxResolutionVertical to 200, and that didn't reduce the size of the video either. What gives? Does it simply ignore this argument?

Answer (score 0):

Got reply from Garmin devs, this is not supported. Issue closed.